# How to sleep in Python 3 and remain in the same line?

Tags: python-3.x, sleep

1. I want to print a message with end=''
2. Sleep for 1 second
3. Remain on the same line
4. Erase the previous message using '\b'
5. Print a new message
6. Back to step 1

Example:

First output:
**1**
Second output:
**2**
Third output:
**3**
*Remains in the same line*

**NOT: 123**

Answer (score 1):

Are you set on using `\b`?  You can use `\r` to move the cursor back to the beginning of the line, which will let you write over stuff that is already there.  If there's a chance that later lines will be shorter than previous ones, you should pad the new lines with whitespace on the right.  Something like:

```
def f(x):
    for i in range(1, x+1):
        print(end='\r', flush=True)
        print('**{}**'.format(i), end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(1)

f(3)
```

Comment: @user8718189 In what way?

Comment: First time.sleep(1) executed and at last; after few seconds only '3' was printed!

Comment: Whatever terminal you're using is buffering the output (waiting for a newline before printing the line). Add `flush=True` to the print calls.

Comment: Thankyou for your support but now it is printing the desired output, when I placed '\r' before the string:
print('\r1', end='')
time.sleep(1)
print('\r2',end='')
time.sleep(1)
print('\r3')